# Traveling to South Korea, Should I buy a type C or F plug adapter?

Tags: south-korea, power

From what I can see, either should plug into either socket. If I am bringing mainly a laptop, a usb, and a camera charger, which style should I buy for best results?

Not sure if the type F is better/more versatile as it has another contact for what I would assume is a ground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of them will be ok.

However, on my opinion, I would prefer type C, because it has more flexibility in using. Also type C can be used in a lot of countries. If you travel a lot it's a big advantage.

More information you may find here: http://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeC.htm

Comment: +1. If it helps, it does not seem (I checked all my plugs and devices in my appartment) that Korea does not use earthing: plugs are mostly type C or type E and sockets are unearthed (German Schuko type F). 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets 

Also, be aware that it is not easy to find adaptators outside airports.

Comment: Actually, you can buy an adapter in any 7eleven shops which are widely spread in Korea